# sudo to the same ordinary user, without authentication

Tags: linux, sudo

My script, when executed as root, uses the sudo  without passwd, and that is fine.
Sometimes however, I must execute that script as an ordinary user, which "switches"
to itself by that sudo command.
I must omit the passwd procedure in this case also.

Currently I use the default (almost empty) sudoers file. I'd like to
extend it with a simple, general, not user-specific rule for the above.

I tried to setup some wildcard rules with * and ALL, but failed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Say that the user that must execute the script is `someuser`, the full path to the script is `/usr/local/bin/somescript`.

Using `visudo`, add the following line

```
someuser ALL=(someuser) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/somescript
```

To execute this (you can omit the full path if the script is in the `$PATH`:

```
someuser@somehost:~$ sudo -u someuser /usr/local/bin/somescript
```

But... there's any reason why you can't execute the command without sudo? There shouldn't be any difference calling it `sudo`'ed this way or just without `sudo`

**update**

If you need to allow all users to execute any command as any user, put the following line (**but take into account that this is a TOTALLY INSECURE AND RISKY configuration**. This would allow any user (first column) to execute on any machine (non-important, 2nd column) any command(fourth column) as any user (third column, between parentheses))

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: "There shouldn't be any difference calling it sudo'ed
 this way or just without sudo"
`You are right. But I have to use the script 'as is'`

Comment: Thanks Carlos, your suggestion seems to be correct, and I will use it if I cannot find a less explicit solution. However, I am looking for a less specialized config. For all users. For all commands. Nothing specific, just the "No difference" phenomenon mentioned above.

Comment: I'd like to specify something like (%Myself) or (%Sameuser) in the parantheses. Then NOPASSWD: would do its job.

Answer (score -2):

You want to execute a script that will run as root, but allow non-privileged users to run it. This means you should enable the [setuid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Comment: scripts cannot use the setuid bit usually, as the interpreter ignores them upon reading the script.